# How to update and sync Docker container files using a volume

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use a volume to edit the project files using Visual Studio Code from a folder on my desktop to sync with a Docker container. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because my changes aren't being shown in the container, even when I manually restart the container. Are there any additional steps needed or did I reference the "www" folders wrong?

The Docker container has an Ubuntu project with files in the /var/www/ directory.

docker run -it -v /Users/.../Desktop/docker/test2/bh_files:/www -v /www/ -p 8080:8080 k/bh:latest

Answer (score 0):

> docker run -it -v /Users/.../Desktop/docker/test2/bh_files:/www -v /www/ -p 8080:8080 k/bh:latest

You are linking your project folder with the `/www/` folder inside your container NOT `/var/www/`. Simply update the path and it should work.

**Edit:** Change your container volume path as `docker run -it -v /Users/.../Desktop/docker/test2/bh_files:/var/www -p 8080:8080 k/bh:latest`

I am not really sure that you need the second volume `-v /www/`. This serves no purpose without a host folder.

Comment: changing it to this didn't fix the issue docker run -it -v /Users/.../Desktop/docker/test2/bh_files:/www -v /var/www/ -p 8080:8080 k/bh:latest

Comment: you have to change it to : docker run -it -v /Users/.../Desktop/docker/test2/bh_files:/var/www -p 8080:8080 k/bh:latest